# Suppose $B$ lies over $A$, s.t. $A,B$ integral domains. Does this tell us anything about which homomorphisms from $A$ to a field we can extend to $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, ideals

> Suppose $B$ lies over $A$, $A,B$ integral domains. Does this tell us anything about which homomorphisms from $A$ to a field we can extend to $B$?

We say $B$ lies over $A$ if, for any prime ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $A$, there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak b$ of $B$ such that $A\cap \mathfrak b = \mathfrak a$.

We do have a theorem telling us that if $B$ is integral over $A$, and $\Omega$ is some algebraically closed field, we can extend a map $A \to \Omega$ to $B \to \Omega$. Are there other results telling us in which ways we can extend a map from $A$ to a field on the basis of knowing $B$ lies over $A$?

Comment: For sure every homomorphism if $B$ lies in the fraction field of $A$

Comment: Why don't you think about the case when $A$ is a field?

Comment: @FreeFunctor thanks for the answer! this might be obvious to you, but why does your result hold?

Comment: @FreeFunctor was probably thinking about the case when the map from $A$ to a field is injective, but their claim is false in general. Anyways I still suggest that you think about the case when $A$ is a field (so your "lies over" condition is trivially satisfied) to calibrate what you can expect to be true

Comment: @math54321 will be working on that case, thanks for the advice!